# Adding dynamic content to a Data Grid in a dynamically created Tab

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, mvvm

In C# WPF MVVM I have implemented a `TabControl` with observable collection and every time I click a certain button, a new tab is created. Inside every tab I want to have a data grid, so I added a data grind into a `TabControl.ContentTemplate`. Now I want to fill the data grid dynamically. Depending on which tab the data grid is in, I want to bind its `ItemsSource` to a certain list. So every tab has a data grid with a list of elements, but these elements are different depending on which tab the data grid is in. How can I make this binding?

I thought about extending the TabItem with a list of elements I want data grid to contain, but I do not know how to access the `TabItem` to which a specific data grid belongs to using XAML.

How can this be done?

Comment: You can create a UserControl with a DataGrid. This UserControl has a View-Model, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding a new `UserControl` and a corresponding ViewModel for it, and then added the crated user control inside the `DataTemplate` tag.